# Finding set? ⋃⋂ ⋂ ((s-1, t+k)\{k/2})

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve:

Find $\bigcup_{k\in N} \bigcap_{t>0} \bigcap_{s<0} \; ((s-1,t+k) \setminus \{\frac{k}{2}\})$

And to be honest, I'm not sure how to get started. I've drawn s-t (s where normally x is and t where normally y is) plane and assumed the solution will be only in the second quarter of it (t>0 and s<0), but what does the rest mean? I think I'm supposed to find set of certain points, but not quite sure if this is the case and if so, then completely unsure how to do it. I'm self studying so can't ask a teacher or something. k is the third dimension I guess?

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Start  inner-out, from the set $⋂_{s<0}((s−1,t+k)∖\{ \frac k 2 \})$. For fixed $t$ and $k$ it is the *intersection* of the intervals $(s−1,t+k)$ each minus the number $\frac k 2$. Try with some computation, write the interval for s=-1, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the (s-1, t+k) were points, not intervals. So after thinking about it my answear is $(-1, \infty)\setminus\{\frac{k}{2}\}, k\in N$. Does it seem to be correct?

Comment: I don't usually just give the answer, but I will here, because I think it will be helpful for you to know, so that you can figure out where you went wrong. The correct answer is $[-1, \infty)$. $-1$ is in the set because it is an element of *every* one of the sets being intersected. When dealing with intersections, You look for what elements are eliminated by not being in some sets. If an element is included in sets, but never eliminated by any of them, it is in the intersection. For unions, you look to see if *any* set includes it, which why you were wrong about the $k/2$ elements.